# Can we restrict visibility of certain stages in Opp but can be changed through apex

Tags: apex, administration

Can we restrict visibility of certain stages in a opp on a standard page. but can be changed to those stages only using apex.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Make them deactivate on field level so it won't be visible on Standard Page. But you can use them in Apex whenever needed.